# A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected

Tags: asp.net

I am Getting this error

`A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtEmbed="<embed src='http://a...").`

when i am opening a modalpopup extender on link button click and in code behind i am assigning the textbox

```
value="<embed src='http://auddia.com/player-viral.swf' height='20' width='200' allowscriptaccess='always' flashvars='volume=100&autostart=false&file=http://auddia.com/Audios/audioStream_1299222864888_19.flv&plugins=viral-1d'/>
```

and also i set the `ValidateRequest="false"` in the page directive's. and in code behind i also use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` . but again and again i am facing this error

`"A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtEmbed="<embed src='http://a...").".`

Please help me ASAP.

Comment: What's the value of txtEmbed that's causing this?

Comment: @Stecya: Where in the world did all that additional information come from? Lots of the stuff you edited in wasn't in the original question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this to your web.config.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
   <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Another option is to write custom validator explained [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/luisabreu/archive/2010/01/05/oh-gosh-validating-user-input-is-extensible.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```